# NUnit failed to load MSTestAdapter/MSTestFramework DLLs and "couldnt find any tests"

Tags: c#, selenium, azure-devops, nunit, mstest

I am doing a unit test with NUnit and i want to integrate it into azure devops.
When i run the test locally in visual studios with test explorer,
the tests are able to run properly without failure.

However, when i build it on azure devops, i encounter the problem of NUnit failing to load the MSTestAdapter and MSTestFramework Dlls or it being unable to find MSTestAdapter/MSTestFramework dlls.

Initially when i looked through, i thought it was because my processor architecture did not match.Thus i tried to create a runsettings file and change the test platform to x64 for NUnit to match the test.
However, it still didnt work and gave me the same error message (will be shown below)

code in Runsettings file which i have tried :

`````
    ```` <RunSettings>
     ````<!-- Configurations that affect the Test Framework -->
     ```` <RunConfiguration>
        ````<TargetPlatform>x64</TargetPlatform>
     ````   <TargetFrameWorkVersion>Framework45</TargetFrameWorkVersion>
     ```` </RunConfiguration>
    ```` </RunSettings>


Just a part of the error messages
The error message is what i get at the VSTest part in azure devops when i build my project

(the messages are all similar) :

Multiple versions of same extension found. Selecting the highest version.
  Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter : 14.0.2505.1
Input string was not in a correct format.
Could not load type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.ExecutionScope' from assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
Could not load type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.ExecutionScope' from assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
Unable to load types from the test source 'd:\a\1\s\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.3.2\build\_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll'. Some or all of the tests in this source may not be discovered.
Input string was not in a correct format.
Unable to load types from the test source 'd:\a\1\s\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.3.2\build\uap10.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll'. Some or all of the tests in this source may not be discovered.
Input string was not in a correct format.
NUnit Adapter 3.12.0.0: Test execution started
Running all tests in d:\a\1\s\HeyX.UnitTest\bin\Debug\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.Interface.dll
   NUnit failed to load d:\a\1\s\HeyX.UnitTest\bin\Debug\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.Interface.dll
Running all tests in d:\a\1\s\HeyX.UnitTest\bin\Debug\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll
   NUnit couldn't find any tests in d:\a\1\s\HeyX.UnitTest\bin\Debug\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll
Running all tests in d:\a\1\s\HeyX.UnitTest\bin\Debug\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll
   NUnit couldn't find any tests in d:\a\1\s\HeyX.UnitTest\bin\Debug\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll
`````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there was something wrong with my visual studios. Not very sure which part of my vs it was that affected my testing, but after reinstalling vs and building from scratch, i am able to build on devops without any error.

Answer (score 1):

What is the framework version and visual studio version of the NUnit project?

In the "visual studio test" task, you can select the visual studio version.

Maybe the version of the NUnit Project is higher than the version of the task.

You can specify the path of the vstestconsole if that is the case.

Comment: Hi Paulo, Im not sure if i understand but i believe the target framework version are all set to net45(?)

Comment: Unsure if this will aid in solving the problem :  Test run will use DLL(s) built for framework .NETFramework,Version=v4.0 and platform X86. Following DLL(s) do not match framework/platform settings.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.Interface.dll is built for Framework 4.5 and Platform AnyCPU.
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll is built for Framework 4.5 and Platform AnyCPU.
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll is built for Framework 4.5 and Platform AnyCPU.

Comment: You say that locally, everything is fine, but in azure devops everything is wrong, with the errors you gave.

![Example, Visual studio task](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/storage/attachments/26815-vstesttask.png).

Here is a screenshot of a sample, where you can change the visual studio version on the test task.
I think you are using this for the test?

Comment: Apparently there was something wrong with my visual studios. Not very sure which part of my vs it was that affected my testing, but after reinstalling vs and building from scratch, i am able to build on devops without any error. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The error indicated “Could not load type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.ExecutionScope' from assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework, Version=14.0.0.0 …”

As 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.ExecutionScope' only applies to [MSTest.TestFrameWork.1.3.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.executionscope?view=mstest-net-1.3.2) or higher. Your test project might reference to the wrong assembly.

Both of the package MSTest.TestAdapter.1.3.2 and package Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.14.0.0  have Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework assembly. But only the one in package MSTest.TestAdapter.1.3.2 have 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.ExecutionScope

You can try to point your “Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework” reference to the folder where MSTest.TestFramework.1.3.2 resides in your test csproj file.

In my own .net framework  test project I changed the value of tag "HintPath"  which resides under tag "reference Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework….." like below:

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL"> 
 <HintPath>..\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.3.2\lib\net45\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll</HintPath>
 </Reference>
 <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">        
<HintPath>..\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.3.2\lib\net45\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
 </Reference>
```